# handsontable - Change cell borders dynamically

Tags: border, cell, handsontable

I use Handsontable , I manage to add dynamically a border cell on a specific cell (row,cell).

But I don't manage to delete/remove it dynamically after.

I'm looking for a solution.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

I share it :

```
function cell_no_border(hot, row, col) {

var bordersMeta = hot.getCellMeta(row, col).borders;
if(bordersMeta != null){
    bordersMeta.top.hide = true;
    bordersMeta.bottom.hide = true;
    bordersMeta.left.hide = true;
    bordersMeta.right.hide = true;
}

var className = 'border_row' + row + 'col' + col;
removeBordersFromDom(className);
```

}